# Prove that all linear transformations are in the form $T(x_1, \dots ,x_n) = (A_{11}x_1 + \dots + A_{1n}x_n, \dots , A_{m1}x_1 + \dots + A_{mn}x_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra

From the definition of a linear transformation, for $x,y \in V$
$T(x+y)=Tx+Ty$ and $T(\lambda x) = \lambda T(x)$

But by the way matrix multiplication is defined, it's clear that when we multiply a $m \times n$ matrix with a $n \times 1$ vector, the transformation must take the form of:

$T(x_1, \dots ,x_n) = (A_{11}x_1 + \dots + A_{1n}x_n, \dots , A_{m1}x_1 + \dots + A_{mn}x_n)$

How can we prove that all linear transformations must take this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $T(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=x_1T(1,0,0,\ldots,0)+x_2T(0,1,0,\ldots,0)+\cdots+x_nT(0,0,0,\ldots,1)$.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. By using this, are we now not just deferring the problem to: Show that $T(1,0,0,...0)$  is in the form of $(A_{11}x_1+ \dots + A_{1n}x_n, 0, 0, \dots, 0)$? I can't see the critical step here

Comment: Never mind. I think i got it. We can let $T(1,0, \dots,0) = (A_{11}, A_{12}, \dots A_{1n})$.  $T(0,1, \dots,0) = (A_{21}, A_{22}, \dots A_{2n})$. So based on your hint, $T(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=x_1(A_{11}, A_{12}, \dots A_{1n})+x_2(A_{21}, A_{22}, \dots A_{2n})+\cdots+x_n(A_{m1}, A_{m2}, \dots A_{mn}) $

Comment: Yes! That was what I meant with my hint.